# Problem with running supervisor in a Docker container

Tags: docker

I have a problem with running Supervisor after configuration.

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
error: <class 'FileNotFoundError'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 560
```

How can I fix it? I tried to install pip3, supervisor, etc., but nothing worked.

My Dockerfile look like:

```
# Use Ubuntu 22.04 base image
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Set environment variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update and install dependencies, Node.js, and utilities
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl fish git nano sudo unzip ca-certificates gnupg lsb-release \
    && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g ts-node@latest pm2@latest nodemon@latest yarn@latest \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user 'm', set password, configure sudo, and set fish as default shell
RUN useradd -m -s /usr/bin/fish m \
    && echo 'm:password' | chpasswd \
    && echo 'root:rootpassword' | chpasswd \
    && echo "m ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | tee /etc/sudoers.d/m


# Create /src/app directory
WORKDIR /src/app
```

Comment: Definitely need more info, because `sudo supervisorctl reread`, respondes with `sudo: supervisorctl: command not found`, and the question seems to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), because it's not about programming.

Comment: I wouldn't normally suggest running supervisord as a preferred path.  What things are you trying to run, and can you run them in separate containers?  Setting fixed plain-text passwords and granting unrestricted sudo access are often significant security mistakes.